# How to find unanswered questions only from all of my questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

1. How to find unanswered questions only from all of my questions?
2. How to find all not accepted yet questions only from all of my questions?
3. How to know my which questions has earned badge?
4. How to search for `answers:0` for a specific tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `answers:0 user:me`
2. `hasaccepted:0 user:me`
3. You can't. Badges are designed not to work this way.
4. `answers:0 [support]`

Comment: This works.  Just some advice to everyone, though: Make sure you're doing this search on the relevant StackExchange site.